# Can a guest user create his account before checkout after adding an item to cart in Magento 2?

Tags: rest, api, magento2, postman, put

I want the guest user to be registered before the checkout process, but after adding an item to the guest cart in Magento 2.

I have figured out the stage at which i was supposed to map the guest cart in postman as shown below. but again its giving error. after creating guest-cart, i have used user guest-carts assign API to map guest-cart to a particular customer.

The cartId generated is 'ccefc695ec22b7e6d1d5e646bd23c4df'

Method: PUT,
API Url: http://10.201.62.75/magento/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/ccefc695ec22b7e6d1d5e646bd23c4df

JSON Body:

```
{
  "customerId": 31,
  "storeId": 1
}
```

The response I am getting is

```
{
 "message": "Cannot assign customer to the given cart. You don't have    permission for this operation.",
"trace": "#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(123): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\GuestCartManagement\\Plugin\\Authorization->beforeAssignCustomer(Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\GuestCart\\GuestCartManagement\\Interceptor), 'ccefc695ec22b7e...', 31, 1)\n#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/var/generation/Magento/Quote/Model/GuestCart/GuestCartManagement/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\GuestCart\\GuestCartManagement\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('assignCustomer', Array, Array)\n#2 [internal function]: Magento\\Quote\\Model\\GuestCart\\GuestCartManagement\\Interceptor->assignCustomer('ccefc695ec22b7e...', 31, 1)\n#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(307): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http))\n#9 {main}"
```

}

I am using Access token for authorization in postman.

Authorization   Bearer 4*********************hi89

Can someone help me with the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I hope it is helpful, when trying your method worked, although it is not with the administrator token, but with the user to whom you will assign it.